# Is it fine if echo $JAVA_HOME shows the same path twice separated with a colon?

Tags: java, ubuntu, java-home

Here is an example of how the result looks like. 
I believe it shouldn't be like that.

```
user@user:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

It also influences maven commands, since I get the following error when running any of maven command:

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

Comment: `JAVA_HOME` should be a single directory location.  You'll need to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to fix that. `JAVA_HOME` should be a single location.

try `export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

and `source ~/.bash_profile` (or set in your `.zshrc` file)

Comment: should it look like this for my case?  export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to solve the issue and set the variables permanently with help of the instruction: https://www.configserverfirewall.com/ubuntu-linux/set-java-home-ubuntu/